# react-native-code-push not working in react native setup

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am using react native , I have added react-native-code-push using pod installation , I am have all steps as per docs  https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-ios.md . able build APP,  I am able to run app success full but when I am trying

import codePush from "react-native-code-push";

console.log ('codePush===', codePush) , getting undefined , and not able open debug menu also , reload and all is stoped working

here is version info

package.json

```
 "react": "16.8.3",
  "react-native": "0.59.8",
 "react-native-code-push": "5.6.0",
```

pod file :

```
  # React Native requirements
 pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket', # Needed for debugging
    'RCTAnimation', # Needed for FlatList and animations running on native UI thread
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
 ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
 pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
 pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
 pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
 pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # CodePush plugin dependency
  pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'
```

[image]

unable to understand issue , any one can help on this issue ,

Comment: any one facing this